# setlocale() not working properly with date()

Tags: php, date, locale

**I have this piece of code:**

```
<?php

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");
    $contador = 1;
    $diaActual = time();

    while ($contador <= 7) {

        echo date("D j-n-Y", $diaActual)."<br><br>";
        $contador++;
        $diaActual = strtotime("+1 day", $diaActual);

    }


?>
```

**Result:**

> Tue 13-5-2014
>
> Wed 14-5-2014
>
> Thu 15-5-2014
>
> Fri 16-5-2014
>
> Sat 17-5-2014
>
> Sun 18-5-2014
>
> Mon 19-5-2014

**Why isn't working?**

Comment: Why was that downvoted? It's actually a legitimate question I think.

Comment: I think there's a lot of trolls here the same on my last questions xD

Comment: Actually, there are some of your questions which really aren't elaborated enough.

Comment: @JuanDelÁrbol In English starting questions with `¿` is not necessary (it's wrong, to be precise). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual about `date()`](http://php.net/date)

> To format dates in other languages, you should use the setlocale() and strftime() functions instead of date().

So use `strftime()`:

```
print strftime("%a %d-%m-%Y");
```

To sum up always one day, just use a timestamp like:

```
for ($time = time(), $contador = 1;
     $contador <= 7;
     $contador++, $time = strtotime('+1 day', $time)) {
    print strftime("%a %d-%m-%Y", $time)."<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Okey this worked, but the last question, how to sum 1 day? because now  $diaActual = strtotime("+1 day", $diaActual); does not work

Comment: Yeah perfect! Thank you so much bwoebi :)